# How to force an IIS App Pool to go into the 'Unknown' state?

Tags: iis, application-pool

How can we force an IIS app pool to go into Unknown state? Is there a way to do this through the inetmgr GUI or through power shell ? I want to test a script that I'm writing, based off the Unknown state of my IIS app pool

Comment: At least, there isn't any documented way to achieve this.

Comment: What does unknown state mean? I don't think IIS currently has the configuration you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, if you log into the IIS server machine with non-admin account, then  go to inetsrv folder and run "appcmd.exe list apppool" in command prompt ,you will get unkown state like below:

[image]

And before that you may need to add this non-admin user access permission to the config folder.

[image]

By the way, are you trying to test Powershell session? using "Get-IISapppool" in powershell with non-admin account will also get an empty state showing.
[image]